# What's the property of a language called which makes you able to write eg. a bootloader?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, terminology, bootloader, low-level

What's the name for a property of a programming language (or of its compiler) which makes one able to write independently of any Operating System and any standard|runtime library?

For example, one can write a boot loader in C or in assembly for a given processor platform. How is this property[|ies] described or named?

Example question: "Is Java a `<term-here>` language, so that I can write a bootloader in it?"

Comment: I'd call this [systems programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_programming).

Comment: Typically, this is not a property of the language but of the compiler E.g. a C compiler that produces Windows PE executables doesn't allow you to write bootloaders. One could imagine a Java compiler that linked in an appropriate JVM, so that you could write a bootloader in Java.

Comment: The standard for the `C` programming language uses the term "freestanding" do define a set of properties making the resulting program compiled from that language to not depend on anything but hardware. For instance, the Linux kernel is an example of a freestanding program written in C. The essential property of being a freestanding is not depending on any libraries and other resources which has to be *fetched* from somewhere such as a file system.

Comment: @MSalters you're right, I've edited the question trying to reflect that!

Comment: @kostix: you seem to be confusing hosted implementations with shared libraries. C does not require libraries to be "fetched from somewhere", they might be statically linked in, and a freestanding implementation can make libraries available at the discretion of the implementer.

Comment: @larsmans, quite possibly yes. The problem is that as soon as we get down to terminology, the question quickly becomes moot because we then have to settle on what does "hosted" precisely mean. I referred to shared libraries to undeline the fact a typical "normal" app written in `C` is quite a complicated beast when it comes to bootstrapping it (I mean all the hard work required from the dynamic linker), so while such an app is not hosted (in a Java sense, I mean) it still relies on an intricate infrastructure to start running. Anyway, I take your point as valid, thanks.

Comment: bare metal is a term that is used for this kind of programming, where you have no operating system and you are doing all the low level work in some way, shape, or form.

Comment: You might be thinking of "portability". Although that usually refers to the ease of "porting" or modifying code to run on different platforms.

Comment: You can't write a bootloader in C for some systems, e.g. x86.  At least not without a bunch of wrapper functions for inline asm, and a 16-bit C compiler, if we're talking about a legacy MBR boot sector.  With the right linker script you could possibly massage it into a flat binary with the right 2-byte boot signature at the end of a 512-byte sector.  It's certainly *easier* to write a bootloader in asm than C, but it might be possible to do something you could describe as writing it in C.